# displaying the range of numbers using the user input excluding the number 13 python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, count, range

I need help trying to display a range of numbers excluding the number 13.
I tried several methods and this is how far i got.
I suspect something is wrong with the logic at the if else.

```
x= input("Enter starting value for x: ")
y= input("Enter starting value for y: ")
if x > y :
    y= y -1
    for y in range(y,x):
         if y==12 or y== 13:
            y = y+2
            print y
         else:
              y = y+1
              print y 
else:  
    for x in range(x-1,y):
        if x==12 or x== 13:
            x = x+2
            print x

        else:
            x = x+1
            print x
```

when the number x become 12 things starts to go wrong.
x=1
y=15
expected output 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
14
15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change the value of x or y during your for-loops (in fact, I would change the value to something different i.e. for i in range(y,x) but the fundamental problem is your checking values and what happens.

The easiest way of doing the check here would be to add a check for the index being 13 and if it's not, then printing the line.

Another issue is over complicating things, you don't need the two almost identical for-loops.

A more simple way to approach this would be along the lines of (pseudocode here, but close to Python )

```
for i in range(min(x,y), max(x,y))
    if not(i==13)
           print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ignore the output of 13 only.
So try this one:

```
if not x == 12:
    x = x+1
    print x 
else:
    # just ignore
    # or do something else
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I've improved your code adding, number-type checking, and less code to compute the range loop, try it:

```
>>> x= input("Enter starting value for x: ") #x=1
>>> y= input("Enter starting value for y: ") #y=15
>>> forbiden_num = 13
>>> try:
...     int(x)
...     int(y)
... except ValueError:
...     print "You must pass integer parameters"
...     import sys
...     sys.exit()
... 
>>> for i in range(min(x,y), max(x,y)):
...     if i == forbiden_num:
...         continue
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
14
```